# nginx custom error configuration referencing a string vs a file

Tags: nginx

I understand that I can set a file for a custom error page:

```
location / {
    error_page 404 = /mybad.html;
}
```

But I'd just like to instead provide my page override as text inline in the config file:

```
 location / {
    error_page 404 = "<H1>Sorry!</H1>"
}
```

Is this possible with nginx?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

```
location / {
    error_page 404 @sorry;
}

location @sorry {
    return 404 "<H1>Sorry!</H1>";
}
```

- http://nginx.org/r/error_page
- http://nginx.org/r/return

Comment: If you're using this with other options, like proxy_pass, you may see the browser's default error. This is because nginx is implying to the browser your text is a binary string. Add `default_type text/html` to your @sorry location block to fix this.

Comment: How can you do this with json instead and it set the content type accordingly?

Comment: Thanks. Worked for me. Had to put `default_type text/html` inside the `location @sorry` section as Jamie suggested.